# Detect with AngularJS when DOM Element is created

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a 3rd-Party Javascript Library which is adding DOM-Elements dynamically on runtime into a div. I'm looking for a way, to detect in AngularJS (Angular 1) when this Element has been created, so I cant perform some specific actions.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="thisElementWasAddedOnRuntime"></div>
</div>
```

I know that there are some JS-Libraries which can detect the creation of a specific Element. But I dont want to include a whole library only for this case.

Comment: This isn't the right way to use angular.  In angular you use the model to drive/derive/create the view you don't depend on the view to do anything really, the model is the source of truth.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background  Learn to use the directives built into the framework to achieve your goal or write custom directives.

Comment: Which third party lib are you using?

Comment: I know. Nevertheless I'm working on a Web Application where I'm facing this problem.

Comment: @lin It's a custom build lib build by a vendor.

Comment: Jap, I went cleaning up to code and did it your way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom directive to make it work right. Please take a look at this simple **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j4998yen/)**. You are able to access the element inside your directive `link` function. There you should bind your third party lib on your element. Directives are markers on a DOM element that tell AngularJS's **HTML compiler** to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element. You could also take a look at the [directives documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrit: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // use element here to bind your lib
        console.log(element);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way to observer dom change in angular is directive's link .

```
link:function(scope,ele,attr){
        if (MutationObserver) {
            observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
               console.log('changed');
            });

            observer.observe(ele[0], {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true
            });
        } else {
            ele[0].addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function (evt) {
               console.log('changed');
            }, false);
        }
      }
```

TRY THIS : http://jsbin.com/pizizatuhi/1/edit?html,js,console,output